# find with order => field divide field (field/field)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

So problem fixed like this. (About find with divide fields)
Need use virtualFields.
In model:

```
class User extends AppModel{
    public $virtualFields = array(
    'ORDER_KD' => 'User.field1 / User.field2'
);
```

In controller:

```
$this->User->find('all', array(
             ...//some conditions etc...
             'order'=> array(
                 "ORDER_KD" => 'desc'), //virtualField
             'limit' => 15                
         ));
```

Thanks [kicaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182823/kicaj)

Comment: Why You edit Your question? Leave another users, mayble will be helped him, but now in Your question is answer.

Comment: Sorry i just newbie here. But i think question title and dialogs more than enought for other users

Comment: Firstly, read short tour: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `virtualFields`, because order `field / field` is used as db column name.